# Разобрать Cursor в определенном порядке

Tags: cursor, android

У меня снова проблемы, Чем дальше в лес тем больше дров)

Нужно разобрать Cursor в таком порядке, в котором ему подаются id

А не сверху вниз по таблице, ID которые мне нужны разбросаны по всей таблице.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно построить соответствие id к позициям в курсоре, а потом прочитать данные в нужном порядке. Вроде того:

```
HashMap<Long, Integer> map = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
while (cursor.getNextPosition()) {
  map.put(cursor.getLong(ID_COLOMN_INDEX), cursor.getPosition());
}
ArrayList<String> interesting_list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Long id: orderedIDs) {
  cursor.moveToPosition(map.get(id));
  list.add(cursor.getString(INTERESTING_COLUMN_INDEX));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Что такое вниз и что такое верх - это конечно загадка века. Что такое разобрать `Cursor` в том порядке в каком подаются `id` - вторая загадка века.

Для сведения, молодой человек, в SQL таблицах отсутствует понятие порядка и тем более верх и низа. Есть порядок выдачи результата запроса типа:

```
SELECT blah-blah ORDER BY <clause> ASC|DESC
```

Comment: private void fullFreinds() {//Список id (410, 352, 481, 280, 594, 136, 7, 448, 93, 127, 494, 488, 39) Как выбрать из db в таком же виде//
     Cursor frienCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAIME, colNames, selection, null, null, null, null);
  if(frienCursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do {String stat = "";
  for (String id: frienCursor.getColumnNames()) {stat = frienCursor.getString(frienCursor.getColumnIndex(id));}
Stations.add(stat);
String ider = frienCursor.getString(0);
Itations.add(ider);
} while (frienCursor.moveToNext());
}
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: Nstatio = " + Stations);
frienCursor.close();


Comment: @smalser А хранить этот список, что мешает? А данные в хэшмапе?

Comment: 1) Я не специалист в java программировании, я еще только учусь
2)Зачем мне его хранить, я его вывожу, но не в том порядке который мне нужен  (410, 352, 481, 280, 594, 136, 7, 448, 93, 127, 494, 488, 39) , а он выводит данные с ид в таком порядке  ~ 7,39, 93, 127, 280 ,352, 410,448, и тд. как его перестроить?

Comment: @smalser может тогда вы вначале немного структуры изучите хотя бы? Если вам, даже после моего комментария, не стало ясно как такое сделать?

Comment: <a href="/users/13980/smalser">@rasmicha</a>,Спасибо разобрался